# How to fix "⚠️Configuring INFO failed." when trying to set ROOT logger level in Spring Boot Admin?

Tags: spring-boot-admin

When clicking the `INFO` button for the ROOT logger, I'm seeing the error `⚠️Configuring INFO failed.`.

I'm also seeing that the `Reset` button is grayed out.

Setting and resetting the log level for other classes and packages works fine.

I'm seeing that `logging.level.root` is set in `application.yml`. Is such a setting enough to prevent it from getting set from Spring Boot Admin?